# Json parse exception while setting mocks in wiremock

Tags: json, wiremock

I have the following JSON using as a mock-to-wire mock server. After including this JSON file, on wire mock server start, I am getting the following error

{
"scenarioName": "Retry Scenario",
"requiredScenarioState": "Authorized",
"newScenarioState": "Started",
"id": "28d9932d-20a9-41f1-a05b-2e080029f914",
"request": {
"urlPathPattern": "/api/Application/Q835YUDX/started",
"method": "GET"
},
"response": {
"status": 200,
"headers": {
"Connection": "close"
},
"transformers": [
"response-template"
]
},
"uuid": "28d9932d-20a9-41f1-a05b-2e080029f914"
}

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" wiremock.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('' (code 65279 / 0xfeff)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: {
"scenarioName": "Retry Scenario",
"requiredScenarioState": "Authorized",
"newScenarioState": "Started",
"id": "28d9932d-20a9-41f1-a05b-2e080029f914",
"request": {
"urlPathPattern": "/api/Application/Q835YUDX/started",
"method": "GET"
},
"response": {
"status": 200,
"headers": {
"Connection": "close"
},
"transformers": [
"response-template"
]
},
"uuid": "28d9932d-20a9-41f1-a05b-2e080029f914"
}
; line: 1, column: 2]
at wiremock.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
at wiremock.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)

Comment: What version of WireMock are you using? I was able to successfully start WireMock with that JSON data using 2.26.3

Comment: I am using wiremock version 2.27 but still I am getting this error while starting the wiremock server

Comment: Unexpected character ('?' (code 65279 / 0xfeff)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"?{ --- this is the error message I am getting. Don't understand what needs to be done for this

Comment: Can you upload the exact Wiremock JSON mapping file you have an issue with somewhere so we can have a look? Can you delete 0xFEFF from the file as it is causing the issue? https://unicodemap.org/details/0xFEFF/index.html is a "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE", why would you need it?

Answer (score 1):

[0xFEFF](https://unicodemap.org/details/0xFEFF/index.html) is a "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE", why would you need it in your JSON file?

Just replace that space with normal space [0x0020](https://unicodemap.org/details/0x0020/index.html).

Comment: I created a new file in the server with the same name(Linux server where my mocks are deployed) and pasted the contents of the mock. Anyhow that worked. Could be the issue with space. Thank you